# Render blocking Javascript at end of body tag - Firefox renders some visual content, Chrome does not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-performance

I am just experimenting with a few performance related optimizations.

As per my understanding, any inline `script` is render blocking and the browser executes it as soon as it is encountered. It also halts the DOM parsing.

So, I am expecting that the inline script I have at the end of the `body` should block rendering and the browser should not show me anything at all until after I dismiss the alert.

Chrome seems to render as per the above understanding, but Firefox first renders the html and then shows the alert.

What can be the reason of this? Does it mean Firefox is not considering the javascript to be render blocking? or does render mean something else in Chrome vs Firefox? Is Firefox somehow optimizing by understanding the fact that the script is towards the end of `body`?

This is the code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
    <script>
      alert('here');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome version: 78
Firefox version: 70

Another observation, chrome behaves differently if the alert is in inline script vs external script. It blocks for alerts in inline script, but does not block for alert in external script.

**UPDATE:** Follow up question: [render-blocking Javascript at end of body tag - inline vs external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471566/render-blocking-javascript-inline-vs-external-script)

Comment: Please don't update questions to incorporate answers, that's not how SO works. Your original question was about blocking on an `alert`, which is answered. Updating the question to ask a new question about an external script makes the question a moving target.

Comment: the actual question was about whether or not scripts are render blocking and how browsers handle it. it hasn't been answered, but there is an update related to usage of alert which I have included. I understand that with the update it has become broad.

Comment: Well, we disagree. I wouldn't have answered this question. But I was able to answer what it used to be. No big deal. :-)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. I would probably ask another follow up question based on the findings. It would be easier for others to answer, as otherwise this question might become too broad.

Comment: This is the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471566/render-blocking-javascript-inline-vs-external-script

Answer (score 3):

`alert` isn't a good tool to use to check for rendering behavior. Browsers are increasingly making `alert` and its cousins less blocking (not just Firefox, Chrome's doing it too, but despite a lot of overlap they may be doing different things; you can read about Chrome's approach [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy)).

So apparently, Firefox is allowing the rendering to go forward, but Chrome isn't in this specific case.

To check rendering behavior, you need to use something blocking that isn't an archaic holdover from the 1990's. :-) One way I've used (though not lately) is to load a script that takes a long time to load. (You can do that by having a local server that sends the script using server-side code that introduces an artificial delay in the process.)

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: changing alert to a long running loop seems to block rendering on all browsers while the loop is running, but changing to an external script does not seem to block rendering. Do browsers handle external scripts differently from inline in terms of render blocking?

Comment: @gaurav5430 - I'm afraid I don't know. :-) It would make sense to me that they would go ahead and render during the network operation, even though that means possibly re-rendering if the script uses `document.write`, but I can't say that I *know* that's true.

Comment: Another observation, chrome behaves differently if the alert is in inline script vs external script. It blocks for alerts in inline script, but does not block for alert in external script.

Answer (score 1):

Render blocking means “blocking any rendering **after** this”.

That’s the very reason for putting JavaScript at the bottom of the page - so it didn’t block any rendering of the page above that. Now of course we have `async` and `defer` to help with that but originally we didn’t.

Comment: So you are suggesting that anything before that Javascript  executes would be rendered? Not sure why but this does not seem to happen with inline script tag with a long 'for' loop. The script runs and then the browser renders the html. (but If the same piece of code is in an external script, the browser renders the html before the script executes)

Comment: This is the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471566/render-blocking-javascript-inline-vs-external-script

Comment: @gaurav5430 - *"Not sure why but this does not seem to happen with inline script tag with a long 'for' loop."* Because in many browsers, the same thread doing the JavaScript is also handling painting the DOM. If that thread is busy, the DOM doesn't get painted. But that thread isn't used for network requests, just the completion of them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
that makes some sense, and also hints at why external scripts may not be render blocking, as in that case the thread would have had time to render before handling the downloaded javascript, but in inline it wouldn't.
This also means that the statement "blocking any rendering after this" might not be true for all browsers, as effectively the rendering is blocked if the same thread is executing the next lines of javascript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This makes life a lot difficult in terms of understanding the critical rendering path, which is the original intent of the question.

Comment: regarding "That’s the very reason for putting JavaScript at the bottom of the page" - another reason might be that script execution requires CSSOM to be available, by having scripts at the bottom, we are kinda making sure that we don't have to wait extra for any css to get downloaded and CSSOM to get created.

Comment: The above info is from:

if at any point we must wait for JavaScript execution, then we will have to first wait for the CSSOM construction to finish. In other words, there is a hard dependency edge between JavaScript and CSS… Stylesheets at the top, scripts at the bottom? Now you know why
https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/deciphering-the-critical-rendering-path/

This article is linked to in google web fundamentals, so I think it is a bit credible.

Comment: @gaurav5430 - Non-`defer`/`async` scripts prevent rendering what follows because they may use `document.write`. That's the primary reason, and also the reason that `async` exists. `async` is basically a promise not to use `document.write`. Scroll down a bit from [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type) and you'll see useful graphs of how `async`, `defer`, and `type="module"` affect script loading and execution.

Answer (score 0):

to debug rendering behavior - try handy tool https://slowfil.es/, instead of setting up local server that responds with the script

see DEMO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- RENDER BLOCKING SCRIPT TAG -->
    <script src="https://slowfil.es/file?type=js&delay=2500"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    rendered content
    <!-- RENDER NON-BLOCKING SCRIPT TAG -->
    <script src="https://slowfil.es/file?type=js&delay=2500"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- THANK YOU FOR YOUR ATTENTION READING THIS, upvote my answer! -->
```

[first paint on the timeline, performance tab chrome devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42wWn.png)